# fetch gmail only answered emails

Tags: ruby, email, gmail, imap

I want to fetch only answered emails from Google mail via IMAP.

There is a flag /Answered but it seems not work. 
For fetch mails on Ruby I wrote

```
imap_privider.fetch(1..15, ["BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]", "FLAGS"])
```

And I got response for letter (which I know for sure is a reply):

```
#<struct Net::IMAP::FetchData
  seqno=14,
  attr=
   {"FLAGS"=>[:Seen],
    "BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]"=>"Subject: RE: salut\r\n\r\n"}>,
```

I think that in attr it should be [:Answered].

So what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message 14 isn't answered, it is an answer. Look at the message it answers, that's where you may find the `\answered` flag.

Note that some/many clients don't bother to set the `\answered` flag.

Another approach would be to retrieve `x-gm-thrid` and `envelope` and look at the thread. If the thread contains just one message, that message has not been answered. If it contains more, the highest-numbered message hasn't been answered, and you may consider that the earlier messages have.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll try this approach with x-gm-thrid and envelope. But when I fetched all mails I didn't see any flags except :Flagged and :Seen. You don't know what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the clients involved don't bother to set \answered. You'll have to use the x-gm-thrid hack or do a full thread analysis using the message-id and references fields.